# Thunderbird 68.1.0 hangs on connection to server

Tags: thunderbird

Thunderbird recently stopped downloading messages from my server. It hangs displaying the following. I recently moved to 68.1.0 on Windows 10.

> email@somewhere.com: Connected to mail.somewhere.com...

The server I am connecting to is my own email server (ubuntu, postfix, dovecot) with a self signed cert. I can connect to it perfectly with an older version of Thunderbird on a different machine. I can't say for sure this is Thunderbirds related yet, but it looks like it.

How do I get to the logs to see what is actually happening?

Comment: Downgrade to 60.9 resolves the problem.

Comment: This may be related to the server using a self-signed cert. I cannot create an exception for it in Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be related to the server using a self-signed certificate. Downgrading to 60.9.0 fixes the issue.

68.1.0 never asked to create an exception for the certificate. Instead it hangs.

A bug for it was already created by someone else.